# Implementing Connectivity: "IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 4 were indexed"

Tags: scikit-learn, epochs

I am trying to implement connectivity as a feature within my code, but am unsure of how to fix this error code. Here is my code up until the point of the error.

```
import mne
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from mne.time_frequency import psd_welch
from mne.connectivity import spectral_connectivity


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_predict

#Importing data
pre = mne.io.read_raw_eeglab('Subject31pre.set')
prop = mne.io.read_raw_eeglab('Subject33prop.set')

#Create events in regular intervals, used as markers to generate epochs
preEvents = mne.make_fixed_length_events(
    pre, id=1, start=0, stop=None, duration=1.0, first_samp=True, overlap=0.0)
propEvents = mne.make_fixed_length_events(
    prop, id=2, start=0, stop=None, duration=1.0, first_samp=True, overlap=0.0)

#Plotting of Power Spectral Density
pre.plot(duration=20, n_channels=64)
pre.plot_psd()
prop.plot(duration=20, n_channels=64)
prop.plot_psd()

#Epoch parameters
event_id = None
tmin = 0
tmax = 1
baseline = None
picks = None
reject = None

#Definition of epochs, for both pre and prop data
preEpochs = mne.Epochs(pre, preEvents, event_id, tmin, tmax, proj=True, baseline=baseline, picks=picks, reject=reject, preload=True)
print(preEpochs)
propEpochs = mne.Epochs(prop, propEvents, event_id, tmin, tmax, proj=True, baseline=baseline, picks=picks, reject=reject, preload=True)
print(propEpochs)

#Merge all epochs into one variable
epochsAll = mne.concatenate_epochs([preEpochs, propEpochs])
print(type(epochsAll))

def eeg_connectivity(epochs):
    FREQ_BANDS = {"delta": [0.5, 4.5],
              "theta": [4.5, 8.5],
              "alpha": [8.5, 11.5],
              "sigma": [11.5, 15.5],
              "beta": [15.5, 30]}
    print("inside: ",type(epochs))


    sfreq = epochs.info['sfreq']

    con, freqs, times, n_epochs, n_tapers = \
        spectral_connectivity(epochs, method='coh', mode='multitaper', sfreq=sfreq,
        fmin=0.5, fmax=30, faverage=True, n_jobs=1)

    freqsNd = np.array(freqs)

    X = []
    for fmin, fmax in FREQ_BANDS.values():
        con_band = con[:, :, (freqsNd >= fmin) & (freqsNd < fmax)].mean(axis=-1)
        X.append(con_band.reshape(len(con), -1))  # -1

    return np.concatenate(X, axis=-1)
```

And here is the error received:

```
  File "", line 71, in eeg_connectivity
    con_band = con[:, :, (freqsNd >= fmin) & (freqsNd < fmax)].mean(axis=-1)
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 4 were indexed
```

Thank you.